Is it safe for an unaccompanied woman to walk downtown streets in Atlanta, USA at day on a weekend?
I am on a business trip in Atlanta. I have two days off and was thinking about exploring the city.
I am staying at the Hilton Atlanta at Courtland Street NE, wanted to visit the Georgia aquarium. It is 16 mins walk from the hotel. I should walk the Baker St in straight line in the west direction of my hotel (14) on this map.
It seems there is no other transportation that takes me there but a taxicab. I had a bad experience with riding a taxi this week; the driver was a pervert and creeped the hell out of me. I also encountered two drug addicts near Peachtree Center, 4 pm this Sunday.
Any safety tips and advice are appreciated.
Update: My definition of safety as a woman is that I don't encounter perverts, drug addicts on the streets, or anything that makes a normal person feel endangered.
For example, at 4 pm near (in daylight), near peachtree center on Sunday .. I encountered drug addidcts .. recognized them by their eyes/faces/physical appearance. One of them followed me for some time and I was carrying luggage and kept saying "come from here, are you looking for a cab" .. I said "no thanks" and changed direction and he kept following me .. this made me feel threatened. I found a cab, and the driver said something perverted to me when I was leaving his car and kept looking at me in the mirrors while driving. This made me feel threatened.

You might get the answers you are looking for if you mention what you consider to safe/dangerous, thus providing with more details and narrowing the scope of the question. (I.e. Perhaps identify criteria that would make an area safe/unsafe.)
https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1967/58919

I don't see that "safe" needs a rigorous definition here.  Even as a man, I feel uncomfortable in some areas of Atlanta.

Safety is complicate. I don't know this area but most US cities are generally safe in "Normal" areas especially during day time. That doesn't mean its always pleasant: you can certainly encounter aggressive pan handlers, people with mental or drug problems etc. Consider taking a Ride Share (Uber, Lyft etc) I found these to be very safe and much more pleasant than regular taxi cabs.

To me this is an XY Problem as it is impossible to walk around any city in the US and not encounter the types of people that you stated make you feel unsafe.  Thus to me the fundamental question that should be asking is then how do you minimize such interactions.

OP, with your permission, I'd like to change the word "single" in the title to "unaccompanied" (or you can change it yourself).

‘don’t encounter perverts’ Perhaps you actually mean sex offenders or sexual predators (or even prostitutes)? It’s a nontrivial probability that any person you meet, no matter where and in what capacity, will have some inclination that would lead to at least some people considering them to be a ‘pervert’. But that does not automatically make them dangerous, and it’s also pretty likely both that you won’t ever notice any indication of that kind of personality quirk and that they don’t have any particular interest in you at all beyond what may be professionally required.

I 100% guarantee that you have encountered clean, well-groomed drug addicts and had no idea that they were in fact drug addicts. I feel "drug addicts" is being used as a code word for homeless people in this question.

This is the type of question I would ask the concierge at the hotel, who will be familiar with the area.

@AustinHemmelgarn indeed, one person's definition of "pervert" is quite different from another's. I'm transgender, a lot of people consider me a "pervert" simply because of that (based on incorrect assumptions of what it means to be transgender), when in fact I'm anything but.

@barbecue You're right and the same is true for alcoholics, but it's obvious the OP (or anyone else asking about safety aspects) means "people whose actual behaviour is dangerous and is caused by drug / alcohol intoxication". Such people are not necessarily homeless. And by far not all homeless people are dangerous (even though many people find the sight of them unpleasant).

This started as a comment, but was growing into a series of comments, so here it is as an answer:

My definition of safety as a woman is that I don't encounter perverts, drug addicts on the streets, or anything that makes a normal person feel endangered.

There are many normal people who don't feel endangered just because they've encountered a drug addict on the streets.   I know because I am one.  Some drug addicts (and some other people) may make me feel threatened, but this relates to their behavior rather than to their condition.  On the other hand, there are also many other normal people do feel endangered simply because they've encountered a drug addict. The difference lies in experience, ability to judge the circumstances, etc.
If you're judging safety based on a person's feeling of safety, you will find that this is naturally very subjective.  Someone who has lived all her life in a rural area is likely to feel at least uneasy in most urban areas, and seriously threatened in some places.  By contrast, someone who has lived her entire life in cities may be uneasy or worse in rural areas at night, whether from wild animals or imagined possible intruders.  This is all completely normal, but the variability in "normal" makes it a difficult way to frame the question.
As to your drug addict at four in the afternoon, he might have been a threat, but probably not.  A lot of street people are looking for a way to hustle someone for a bit of money.  Most likely, he would have helped you get a cab and then asked you for some money in return.  Of course, that might not be the case, and the safest thing to do is not to engage at all.
Now the taxi driver saying inappropriate things is entirely unacceptable regardless.  If it was a licensed taxi, in most cities there will be a phone number posted in the vehicle for the taxi commission, where you can report this.  If the number isn't there, look it up online or ask the hotel staff to help you find it.  If you let the driver know that you're aware of the complaint number, you will usually see a rapid improvement in behavior.
I would recommend asking hotel staff (or anyone else local such as a shopkeeper) how to get to your destination.  They may recommend a specific route or identify places to avoid; they may tell you to take a taxi.
The signs of a properly licensed taxi differ from one city to the next; Atlanta's seem to identify the operating business on the vehicle's exterior and to carry a four digit identification number.  Take this number.  If the driver's hack license is posted inside the car (some cities require this), take a picture of it.  If the driver does something inappropriate, mention that you know how to submit a complaint.  If necessary, call the police.  You're very unlikely to need to call the police, but, importantly, the driver knows that you can.
As others have noted, you can't ensure 100% safety anywhere; you have to decide what your threshold is, what risks you can tolerate, and so on.  The trick is to be able to change a situation where you feel unsafe into one where you feel safer.  Local knowledge helps with this, so ask around.

Sorry for the DV but I think it does not answer the question "is it safe for a single woman to walk downtown streets in Atlanta with safety criteria being not encountering perverts, drug addicts, etc". The answer first complains about the criteria being bad and then gives some examples of what to do in some situations (which is at least asked about by the OP)

@mintay Well, I think it's not unreasonable to comment on the question's assumptions, which the answer disagrees with. It obviously affects the answers you will get.

@RichardRast I definitely agree that it is reasonable to comment on question assumptions. However, this particular case seems to challenge a relatively less significant part "anything that makes a normal person feel endangered" and reads like "you feel threatened? well don't", which IMO is not the most reasonable approach to people's fears

Even better, a lot of the people OP claims to feel uncomfortable around by broad categories she'd not even recognise as such. Take my mother (may she rest in peace). She was an alcoholic but never looked like a stereotypical drunk street bum. If you'd met her when sober (she only drank, and heavily, at home and we ensured she never ventured outside when drunk) you'd not know she was an alcoholic at all.

On average it's safe. I've been in that area, there are a lot of people during the day, a lot of tourists and visitors, since that's an area with a high concentration of local points of interest. There's also a lot of visible law enforcement.
Whether you personally will be safe is unknown, obviously, and even buffed up males can be assaulted in the middle of high traffic touristy areas in major cities with a lot of police presence around. But on average you should be fine.
Also, feeling threatened doesn't equate to being threatened. That said, if you feel uncomfortable - try to find a crowded area with a lot of people, don't hail cabs but instead order through an app (uber/lyft/other taxicab apps - these don't hesitate to cut drivers loose if complaints come), and be aware of your surroundings. If the feeling persists - have your phone handy to dial 911.

What if the situation prevents dialing 911?  Just say clearly "Siri, dial 911."  Even if it doesn't work, it might discourage further aggression.  If it does work, the dispatcher will be able to hear the voices and sounds around you..
